# How to use in node properties for deployment and local usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment

I've created node application which I can run locally and in the cloud 
Now I want that it be done somehow smoother and cleaner ,so I try to put some property in config.json file to check if I want to deploy the app or use it locally but I need to update manually this property before I change the propose , there is a better way to do it with node ?

```
let runnerServer = `http://localhost:8060/service/runner/${server.address().port}`;
if (cfg.isHosted) {
    blogServer = `http://${serverName}/service/runner/${server.address().port}`;
}
```

and in the conig.json I've the field isHosted which I change manually(true/false) if I want to deploy or not...

**update**

maybe I can use process.env.PORT but this is just one example that I need to use in my code , currently I've several of fork that need to konw if Im in deployment or running locally ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use use node's in built object called `process.env` (https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) and use two config files per se. This approach is somewhat similar to what you are doing but may be *cleaner*

1. config.localhost.json
2. config.production.json

then by setting properties on this object based on environment such as `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'localhost'` or `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'`, you could read the corresponding file to import the configurations.

```
var config =  require('./config.production.json');
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'localhost')
{ 
    config = require('./config.localhost.json');
}
```

So to set this environment variable when running locally on your dev box , if

OSX - then on terminal `export NODE_ENV=localhost`

WINDOWS - then on cmd line  `set NODE_ENV=localhost`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve this, if every environment configuration can be in the repo:

**config.json**:

```
production: {
  // prod config
},
staging: {
  // staging config
},
devel: {
  // devel config
}
```

**config.js**:

```
const environment = process.env['NODE_ENV'] || 'devel';
module.exports = require('./config.json')[environment];
```

then in your package.json you could add the following scripts:

**package.json**

```
// npm stuff
scripts {
  prod: "ENV=production node index.js",
  stage: "ENV=staging node index.js",
  dev: "ENV=devel node index.js"
}
```

and with this setup, you can run each configuration with the following commands:

- **production**: `npm run prod`
- **staging**: `npm run stage`
- **devel**: `npm run dev`